# Proving the image of a surjective function is Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology, open-map

Show that if $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is an open surjection such that $Gf$, graph of  $f$,  is closed, then $Y$ is Hausdorff.

What does it mean $Gf$ closed?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: thanks..................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set-theoretically, a function $f\colon X\to Y$ is (along with knowledge of the domain and codomain) a subset of $X\times Y$, call the graph $Gf=\{(x,f(x))|x\in X\}.$

When dealing with topological spaces, now $Gf$ is a subset of the topological space $X\times Y$, endowed with the product topology. As such we may ask whether it may be open or closed or both or neither, as in any topological space. In this context, it means what it always means; that the limit of every set in $Gf$ is in $Gf$. That the complement is open, so that every point in $X\times Y\setminus Gf$ has an neighborhood entirely within $X\times Y\setminus Gf$.

Comment: but how can I use this fact?

Comment: Here's an idea. If $y_1,y_2$ are two points in $Y$, then by surjectivity there exist points $x_1,x_2$ with $f(x_1)=y_1$ and $f(x_2)=y_2.$ If $Y$ has more than one point, then so does $X$, and $X\times Y$ has four or more points. Hence there exists a point $(x_1,y_1')$ which is _not_ in the graph. So $f(x_1)\neq y_1'$, and another so that $f(x_2)\neq y_2'.$ Since the complement of the graph is open, there exist neighborhoods $U_1,U_2$ around these points in $X\times Y$. Projection is open so we get open sets $\text{proj}(U_1)$ and $\text{proj}(U_1)$ in $X$. Perhaps you can finish from here?